# Scikit-learn and data visusalisation: Why do I have to use ravel when I use predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I have a function here that visualises the classification made by a certain classifier like Logistic Regression or simply the perceptron model. But I don't get several things:

X has n examples and just 2 features.

1. Why do I have to use xx1.ravel() and xx2.ravel() and then transpose the entire array for classifier.predict? Why can't I simply predict the outcomes using the original dimensions?

2.Why do I need to reshape Z back to the original xx1 shape?

3. Why is there a need to create a meshgrid for plotting a scatter plot? Does the specific points in the meshgrid act like 'pixels' that represent a certain point on the grid? Why is this needed anyway?
4. What is the idx value in idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)), when all I get when I use unique is simply the unique id of the outcomes?
5. What is the use of c = cmap(idx) in the scatter function? Why can cmap take in an argument?

I apologise for the latter questions that may not fit with the topic question. 
The code is taken from the Python Machine Learning book.

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, test_idx = None, resolution = 0.002):
    #Setup marker generator and color map
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red','blue','green','gray','cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    #MESHGRID - plot decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min(), X[:, 0].max()
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min(), X[:, 1].max()
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    # print 'meshgrid:', xx1, xx2

    #CLASSIFIER PREDICT
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha = 0.4, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x = X[y == cl, 0], y = X[y == cl, 1], alpha = 0.8, c = cmap(idx), marker = markers[idx], label =cl)

    #highlight test samples
    if test_idx:
        XTest, yTest = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]
        plt.scatter(XTest[:,0], XTest[:,1], c = '', alpha = 1.0, linewidth = 1, marker = 'o', s = 55, label = 'test set')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the original dimensions"?

Comment: Your questions 3-5 are not really related to the title of your question and should probably be asked separately.  (Question 3 doesn't make sense because this code doesn't use meshgrid for the scatterplot.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This business with meshgrid and ravel is simply a way of taking the cartesian product of the coordinate ranges in order to get a set of (x, y) coordinate pairs representing individual points in a region.

The classifier expects its input to be an Nx2 array, where N is the number of samples (i.e., cases whose class you want to predict).  It wants two columns because there are two features.

Meshgrid produces two arrays, one containing the X coordinates of points in a specified rectangular region, and the other containing the Y coordinates of those points.  By using `.ravel()`, you roll out these arrays into lists of coordinates.  This is just a somewhat confusing way of taking the cartesian product of the desired coordinate ranges.  In other words, this:

```
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
coord1, coord2 = xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
coord1, coord2 = zip(*itertools.product(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution)))
```

You can see this with a simple example:

```
>>> xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(2))
>>> coord1, coord2 = xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()
>>> coord1
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> coord2
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
>>> coord1, coord2 = zip(*itertools.product(np.arange(3), np.arange(2)))
>>> coord1
(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2)
>>> coord2
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

You can see that the same x/y pairs are generated there (although they are generated in different orders).

The meshgrid approach was probably chosen here because it's needed for contourf.  `contourf` essentially takes an "XY plane" as input (consisting of arrays of X and Y coordinates) along with an array of Z values for each point in that plane.

The upshot is that the classifier and the contour plot expect input in different formats.  The classifier takes two individual values (the two input features) and returns a single value (the class it predicts).  `contourf` requires a rectangular grid of points.  In other words, loosely speaking, `predict` wants one X coordinate and one Y coordinate at a time, but `contourf` wants all the X coordinates first and then all the Y coordinates.  The code you posted is doing some reshaping to convert between these two formats.  You generate X and Y in the format `contourf` wants, and reshape it into the format `predict` wants so you can pass it to `predict`.  `predict` gives you the Z data in the shape `predict` likes, and then you reshape that back into the format `contourf` wants.